# Primefaces datatable selection on page refresh

Tags: jsf, primefaces

[image]

Am on *Primefaces* 11. In the above screenshot if I select and apply ***Open*** status then it changes but the *selection* stays as shown in the below screenshot. --- (**Case** 1)

[image]

Now, if I search for *Trolley* type below is what I get (**Case** 2) -

[image]

I tried `PF('wvar').unselectAllRows()` and clearing or setting the selection to null in the backing bean (**Session Scoped**).

Now, if I bump the *PF* version from *11* -> *12* , this ***fixes*** the above 2 issues.

**Case** 3 - on *PF* 12 after applying the status the data table selection is cleared but if I use the browser refresh first the row selection starts showing and if I refresh again the split button on top left also starts showing *row selected*.

This happens on PF11 as well - I tried `PF('wvar').unselectAllRows()` for clearing the selection on *oncomplete* event but browser refresh brings the selection back.

I need to know why the browser refresh behaving the way it is and is there a way to overcome this in PF12 atleast.

PF11, Wildfly11 & JDK8. Also, here the link to all the [files](https://github.com/trawat/mvce)

Comment: Would be best to create a PrimeFaces Test reproducer so devs can actually see and debug what you are doing.

Comment: @Melloware not sure what you meant by `Primefaces Test reproducer` . Have shared github project link already. Created a discussion on PF. https://github.com/orgs/primefaces/discussions/552 as well.

Comment: Please see https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces-test

Comment: Fix added in https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/11146 (PF14)